# Can we use the verb “ache” verb in continuous constructions like “is aching“?

Tags: word-usage, progressive-aspect, stative-verbs

Does it sound ok to use the *‑ing* form of the intransitive verb *ache* meaning hurt?

1. My stomach is aching.

instead of the simple verb:

2. My stomach aches.

In other words, can we use the verb *ache* verb in *to be aching*
continuous constructions such *is/was aching, has/had been aching*?

If the progressive and the non-progressive forms of the verb can both be
used, which of the two is more common and comes more naturally to native
speakers?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

In *The Gondoliers*, W.S. Gilbert has the chorus of girls sing:

By a law of maiden's making,

Accents of a heart that's aching,

Even though that heart be breaking,

Should by maiden be unsaid.

Answer (score 0):

Idiomatically I'd say "I have a stomach ache", using "ache" as a noun.

You can use "is aching" to suggest that the ache is temporary.